# Why am I not getting status code in Jasmine test case?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am doing a rest call in a following manner

```
            updateOperation = function (UUID) {
                 var deferred = $q.defer(),
                     restApiPath = restApiBasePath + UUID + "/_update",
                     updateSuccess = function () {
                         deferred.resolve();
                     },
                     updateFailure = function (errorObj) {
                         deferred.reject(errorObj);
                     };
                 xyzService.invokeREST("PUT", restApiPath, updateSuccess , updateFailure ,true);
                 return deferred.promise;
             }
```

And my test case looks like this

```
         it("should call update & resolve promise when http response is", function() {
              $httpBackend.expectPUT(getValidURL).respond(200, true);
              taskService.updateOperation(UUID).then(function(status,data){
                  expect(status).toEqual(200);
              });
              $httpBackend.flush();
          });
```

**xyzService**

```
                invokeRest = function(httpMethod, serviceURL, successCB, failureCB, retainJSON, postData) {
                    var self = this,
                        requestHeaderDefaults = {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                        },
                        $http({
                            method: httpMethod,
                            url: serviceURL,
                            data: postData || {},
                            headers: requestHeaderDefaults
                        })
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                            successCB(data);
                            return data;
                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            failureCB(data);
                            return data;
                        });

                },
```

Here I am getting both data as well as status as `undefined`. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Can you show us invokeREST function?

Comment: Ok. But isn't it should take the values from provided mock `$httpBackend.expectPUT(getValidURL).respond(200, true);`

Comment: deferred.resolve('200');?

Comment: It is working but I don't thinks this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @zxxc with string '200' it is working. but with an integer, it ain't working for eg. deferred.resolve(200) is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the promise is resolved to `undefined`:

```
deferred.resolve();
```

`then` function has a single parameter, which is resolved value, while it is expected to have multiple parameters, this won't work:

```
taskService.updateOperation(UUID).then(function(status,data){
...
```

Comment: There's no way to do that for the code above, because it's ignored in updateOperation. Since you omitted xyzService and invokeREST, you're the only person who knows how it works.

Comment: I modified success call back to `deferred.resolve(status)` and `$httpBackend.expectPUT(getValidURL).respond('200');` and everything is working fine but when I pass `200` int value I am getting undefined.

Comment: There is no `status` in the code you've posted. Please, update the question to contain all relevant code, including 'xyzService'.

Comment: $http `success` and `error` are deprecated. Use `then` and `catch`. The difference is that they accept a single param, `response` that has both `data` and `success` props, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage . Comma operator is antipattern. `invokeRest` should return a promise, at least for testability reasons. Actually, `updateOperation` contains deferred antipattern too and uses callbacks for no good reason. It should just return a promise from `invokeRest`. That's usual example when testablity defines how the app should be refactored.

Comment: Actually JSON.parse is not needed too, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations . `invokeRest` should return a promise, contain just `return $http({ ... })` and accept no callbacks.